# show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally disconnected

Tags: general-topology

Show that $(\mathbb{Z},d)$ is totally disconnected (where $d$ is the metric induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$).

I think that to prove this I should use contradiction but not really sure where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a space is totally disconnected if its points are open, and in this case $\mathbb Z$'s points are open.  You can prove that by noting that $(n-1/2,n+1/2)\cap\mathbb Z=\{n\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Whoever negged me, that was rude.  How about explaining the problem with my solution?

Comment: This answer can be read as implying that the definition of total disconnectedness is that all singletons are open, which isn't true.

Comment: Only if you're reading it incorrectly.

Comment: @ArthurFischer That's why I was careful to say "in this case".

Comment: now lets n=2 , the (n-1/2,n+1/2)=(1.5,2.5), hence we see its open for n∈Z. I understand that... but why (1.5,2.5)={n}? just getting confused

Comment: @ann It's not that $(1.5,2.5)=\{n\}$.  It's $(1.5,2.5)\cap\mathbb Z=\{n\}$.  In other words if you *intersect* $(1.5,2.5)$ with $\mathbb Z$ then you get exactly $\{2\}$.  And that's what it means to be open in $\mathbb Z$, a set $U\subseteq\mathbb Z$ is open in $\mathbb Z$ if there is an open set $V\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $V\cap\mathbb Z= U$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it does, thank you.. Just been looking to that too long :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can you find neighbourhoods around each $x \in \mathbb Z$ such that the neighbourhoods are completely disjoint?